Deploying R shiny app in Azure as App Service using Docker
I am new to the concept of deployment of apps as app service in Azure using Docker.
I have a R Shiny application that I have deployed in Azure as an app service using Docker.
Here are few details for reference:

Azure Resource Group - Test_RG
Azure Container Registry - Test_CR
Azure App service name - Test_app

In the R shiny script, I have provided the below details for the application port
### Specify application port ### options(shiny.host = "0.0.0.0") options(shiny.port = 8080)
Now this application deployment is successful and I can access the app service through my browser.
Issue arises when I am trying to deploy another R shiny application in the same Azure Resource Group (Test_RG) and same Azure Container Registry (Test_CR).
In the second R shiny script, I have mentioned another application port to avoid conflict
### Specify application port ### options(shiny.host = "0.0.0.0") options(shiny.port = 8000)
In terms of deployment in Azure, I don't get any issues but when I am trying to access the app service, nothing is coming up.
Can someone help to figure out what exactly is the issue or if I am doing anything incorrectly ?
My understanding is that I can deploy multiple app services in a single Container Registry but with different ports to avoid conflict ?
Any help would be appreciated !

Are you deploying the 2nd image to the first app service?

In container registry (ACR) you can deploy multiple images but where as in app service you can't do that you can deploy only one image.

Azure App Service is designed to run a single Docker container image per instance. Each instance is allocated its own resources and runs independently.

@SureshChikkam No, I am trying to deploy the second image as different app service to the same container registry as the first app service. So it would be the same container registry but another app service. Will that create any issues ?

@SureshChikkam, and what should be the logic for the port for the 2nd image deployed in the same container registry in Azure ?

There will be no issue if you take another app service for 2nd image. Go to deployment_center of the app service<In main container mention your second application's port, which is 8000 in the Port section

I believe that Azure expects port 80.  Try this as the final lines in the Dockerfile.
# launch app
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/code', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 80)"]


Basically, in your first application you have mentioned that port number as 8080 but here in app service there will be default port 80 and it will run in 80 as the same in the application.

Whereas coming to second application here you configured the port number in application but not in app service one way you can configure while creating app service.


Another way: After deployment.

Here, you need to configure the port number in app service<deployment center<main<port here you can change the port to 8000.


After changing the port number, you can be able to access the application if your first application works successfully.
